# Secondary literature/reading guide for Marx's Das Kapital

Tags: marxism

I'm looking to read Marx's Das Kapital, but I'm worried (especially after reading the first chapter) that the form of exposition requires a secondary perspective for someone who is not a Marx scholar. I'm thinking that maybe I lack the context and extensive understanding of the historical literature to be able to directly read Das Kapital as primary literature.

For that reason, I'm looking for secondary literature aimed specifically at helping read Das Kapital (i.e., I'd like help reading the book itself, contextualizing, understanding idiosyncratic terminology, etc.), and not summaries or interpretations (although it is perfectly understandable that there is some degree of interpretation in any attempt to help make a text clearer).

Would someone have recommendations on books, articles, etc., in that sense? I'm looking to read it from an economics perspective, and not, e.g., from the point of view of academic philosophy, etc. If possible, I'm looking to avoid authors from the analytic marxism tradition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want contemporary economics perspective you can read the chapters on Marxism in Grant and Brue The History of Economic Thought 7th edition.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137671/discussion-on-answer-by-1muflon1-secondary-literature-reading-guide-for-marxs-d).

Comment: Thank you for the reference!